# What is the difference between `select` and `combobox` in vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

In the `vuetify` documentation you can see two similar controls i.e `select` and `combobox`. They both are providing same functionality I guess. What is the difference between these two?

[Combobox](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox#introduction)

[Select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#introduction)

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the documentation:

**[Select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects):**

> Select fields components are used for collecting user provided information **from a list of options**.

**[Combobox](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox):**

> With combobox you can allow a user to **create new values that may not be present** in a provided items list.

They could be merged? If there is no deep physical or technical difference between the two, I think it is considerable -like adding a boolean `editable` attribute or so.

Comment: `They could be merged?` Good point. This is what WPF does.

Answer (score 1):

Combobox allow user to create new values, that doesn't exist in list. Select don't have such ability.